# Handle overdate in class

Tags: python-2.7, class, date

How to handle overdate in `class date` and `class delta`
here is my code for `class date`.

```
class date(object):
    def __init__(self, year, month, day):
        self.year=year
        self.month=month
        self.day=day
    def __add__(self, era):
        year=self.year+era.year
        month=self.month+era.month
        day=self.day+era.day
        return date(year, month, day)
    def __str__(self):
        return "("+",".join(map(str,(self.year,self.month,self.day)))+")"
```

and this is for `class delta`

```
class delta(object):
    def __init__(self, year=1978, month=12, day=30):
        self.year=year
        self.month=month
        self.day=day
    def __add__(self, era):
        return self+era
```

if i give command like this.

`>>> date(2016, 5, 30)+delta(year=5, month=3, day=30)`

must be 
`date(2021, 9, 1)`

not like this
`date(2012, 8, 60)`

max for `month` must `12`, and for `day` is `30`

This code without using `import`

i'm using python2.7

Answer (score 0):

Just use the builtin `datetime` module which includes a `timedelta` class which does what your `delta` does.  It's included in Python, no need to reinvent it.

Comment: this my homework, and not allowed using any `import`

Comment: @Helonder777: If it's your homework, do it yourself.